# Get Server Name By Invite Discord.js v14

Tags: discord.js

How i can get discord server name by invite discord.js v14

I used: `const guild = await message.client.fetchInvite(message.content);`

but I think that I need to get only invite without message but I dont know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overcomplicating this. You don't need Discord.JS for that you can just query the API, which is public for invites.

You can fetch the endpoint `https://discordapp.com/api/v6/invites/<invite code>`

The returned JSON will contain the name in `response.guild.name`.

For example:

```js
fetch('https://discordapp.com/api/v6/invites/djs')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res.guild.name))
```

Comment: But i need to get invite from message first but it works

Comment: @Kitki30 can you clarify your question then ? From what I understood you wanted to know how to get the server's name from its invite. Which is what I answered to.